# Impact of hurricanes on flights that have to traverse affected areas

Tags: commercial-aviation, extreme-weather

Hurricane Florence is forecast to reach the US east coast soon as a very strong hurricane. This makes me wonder if hurricanes have a big impact on commercial flights that have to traverse the area affected by an hurricane?

Comment: Related: [Do airlines continue operating in the vicinity of a hurricane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9048/1696)

Comment: Hm, actually it might not be a duplicate. That question is about airport operations, but this one is about traversing. That effectively means whether the aircraft can cross above the hurricane safely.

Comment: I've edited to make this a general question about how hurricanes affect planes that want to cross them, rather than a request for predictions about what Florence will do. I hope that makes the question answerable in a concrete way.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We also [have a question already](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22338/62) about flying *over* hurricanes

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks: I think that covers it.

Comment: G Bach, I hope you don't think we've messed you around, here. We can't really predict what this specific hurricane will do, but I think the two duplicate questions do cover most of the aspects you were looking for, at least in general terms. If there's something more specific that you want answered and that isn't covered by those two questions, please do post a new question about that and we'll do our best to answer.